# Ветры и ветра

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: "ветры" или "ветра"?

Answer (score 2):

Нормативно - ветры. "Ветра" встречается в профессиональной речи моряков.

Answer (score 2):

**behemothus** +1

У Владимира Высоцкого есть так называемые *морские песни*, и среди них "Мы говорим не штормы". Там как раз о морских словечках. **Amano**, запомните 1-ый куплет, там ответ на Ваш вопрос :-)

Мы говорим не "штормы", а "шторма" -
Слова выходят коротки и смачны:
"Ветра" - не "ветры" - сводят нас с ума,
Из палуб выкорчевывая мачты.

Мы на приметы наложили вето -
Мы чтим чутье компАсов и носов.
Упругие тугие мышцы ветра
Натягивают кожу парусов.

[весь текст здесь](http://www.pesenki.ru/authors/visockii-vladimir/mi-govorim-ne-6tormi-lyrics.shtml)

Comment: Вдадимир Семенович, тут, похоже, погорчился. "Ветра" мотивировано такими словами как "вечера", "Хутора" и проч. Вот только беглая гласная препятствует. "Шторма" - от односложного "шторм" - ну никак слух не ласкает.

Answer (score -1):

Владимир Семёнович никак не погорячился. Он сценической речи пять лет учился. А там не забалуешь... Так что *ветра* и *шторма* -- это сленговые словечки моряков, а все остальные пусть говорят правильно.

Comment: Вы подробнее пишите. Ответ должен читаться в отрыве от остальных.

Comment: Действительно, при чем тут Семеныч?